# Why does AddGeometryColumn error using the libspatialite-2 DLL with pysqlite2?

Tags: spatial-database, spatialite, python-2.6, windows-7

What I'm trying to achieve is to create a geometry column of a point based on the latitude and longitude of that particular row in the already created table.

Given the following code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('adde.sqlite')
conn.enable_load_extension(True)
conn.execute("SELECT load_extension('libspatialite-2.dll');")
conn.execute("SELECT InitSpatialMetadata();")
conn.enable_load_extension(False)
conn.execute("SELECT AddGeometryColumn('coords','geom_column', 4326, 'Point', 2);")
conn.execute("UPDATE coords SET geom_column = GEOMETRYFROMTEXT('POINT('||longitude||' '||latitude||')', 4326);")
conn.close()
```

I receive the error:

```
AddGeometryColumn() error: "insert on table 'geometry_columns' violates constraint: 'spatial_ref_sys.srid'"
```

I've been able to create the column in the Spatialite GUI no problem, but I'd like to do all of this programmatically using Python.  I've searched for a while now and I'm coming up a bit short.  Any guidance as to why I'm receiving this particular error would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using Python 2.6 and pysqlite2 on Windows 7 64-bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by inserting the definition for the required SRS into the database before adding the geometry column:

conn.execute("INSERT INTO spatial_ref_sys (srid, auth_name, auth_srid, ref_sys_name, proj4text) VALUES (4326, 'epsg', 4326, 'WGS 84', '+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs')")